# Can't install pandas

Tags: python, pandas

When i install pandas i keep getting this error - hopefully somewhere here can help me otherwise I will factory reset my laptop.

Have tried

1. reinstalling vsbuild
2. removing pip cache (`pip cache purge`)
3. upgrading to latest pip

```
Collecting pandas
  Using cached pandas-2.1.4.tar.gz (4.3 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [12 lines of output]
      + meson setup C:\Users\Turan Munday\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7iozznjn\pandas_b08ce326f54c4614a404ddf474364a76 C:\Users\Turan Munday\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7iozznjn\pandas_b08ce326f54c4614a404ddf474364a76\.mesonpy
-_bl8350i\build -Dbuildtype=release -Db_ndebug=if-release -Db_vscrt=md --vsenv --native-file=C:\Users\Turan Munday\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7iozznjn\pandas_b08ce326f54c4614a404ddf474364a76\.mesonpy-_bl8350i\build\meson-python-native-file.ini
      The Meson build system
      Version: 1.2.1
      Source dir: C:\Users\Turan Munday\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7iozznjn\pandas_b08ce326f54c4614a404ddf474364a76
      Build dir: C:\Users\Turan Munday\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7iozznjn\pandas_b08ce326f54c4614a404ddf474364a76\.mesonpy-_bl8350i\build
      Build type: native build
      Project name: pandas
      Project version: 2.1.4

      ..\..\meson.build:2:0: ERROR: Could not parse vswhere.exe output

      A full log can be found at C:\Users\Turan Munday\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7iozznjn\pandas_b08ce326f54c4614a404ddf474364a76\.mesonpy-_bl8350i\build\meson-logs\meson-log.txt
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Comment: Are you using a 32-bit Python or a 64 bit one?

Comment: And which version of Python are you using?

Answer (score 0):

run the code below. sometimes these issues are caused by lack of permissions to do system-wide package install. so running it on a user-level will solve the issue.

```
pip install pandas --user
```